# How to disable profile script in WSL Ubuntu 2004?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I added some lines in `/etc/profile` to set WSL IP address to a fixed one, and it worked perfectly. However, the next day WSL cannot start, even `wsl --help` stucks forever. I highly suspect the `/etc/profile` is the problem, so is there a way to start WSL without running the profile script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use WSL's `-exec` or `-e` to execute a command in place of the default login shell:

```
--exec, -e <CommandLine>
    Execute the specified command without using the default Linux shell.
```

So either start a different shell

```
wsl -e /bin/dash
```

or execute the default /bin/bash with the `--noprofile` option, to skip loading of default profile files, including the system-wide /etc/profile:

```
wsl -e /bin/bash --noprofile
```